# Help me understand log4j appender additivity with respect to priority level

Tags: log4j

I am confused as to why INFO statements are making it to the Console. Here is the general setup:

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
    <layout .../>
</appender>

<appender name="REST_LOG" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="/logs/rest.log" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
    ....
</appender>

<category name="xyz.web">
    <priority value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</category>

<category name="xyz.web.rest">
    <priority value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="REST_LOG" />
</category>
```

So I want INFO and above statements to only do to REST_LOG and WARN statements and above to go to REST_LOG and CONSOLE. What I am seeing is INFO statements from xyz.web.rest in the REST_LOG as expected but also seeing INFO statements from xyz.web.rest in CONSOLE which I wasn't expecting.

Can somebody explain what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thresholds are hierarchical.  DEBUG includes all INFO, WARN, ERROR.  So it is natural that if you define console with a threshold of DEBUG that it would receive INFO level messages.

If you only want console to receive WARN and ERROR, set its threshold to WARN.

Answer (score 5):

You should set additivity to false on the `xyz.web.rest` logger.

Without the additivity you will see all the `INFO` message logged with logger `xyz.web.rest` twice in the console, because the logger inherit the appender of Root logger
and of the `xyz.web` logger.

See the [Appenders and Layouts](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) section of the Log4j documentation

> **Named Hierarchy**
>   A logger is said to be an ancestor of another logger
>   if its name followed by a dot is a prefix of the descendant logger
>   name. A logger is said to be a parent of a child logger if there are
>   no ancestors between itself and the descendant logger.
>
> For example, the logger named "com.foo" is a parent of the logger
>   named "com.foo.Bar". Similarly, "java" is a parent of "java.util" and
>   an ancestor of "java.util.Vector". This naming scheme should be
>   familiar to most developers.
>
> The root logger resides at the top of the logger hierarchy. It is exceptional in two ways:
>
> 1. it always exists,
> 2. it cannot be retrieved by name.
>
> **Appenders and Layouts**
>
> **Each enabled logging request for a given logger will be forwarded to
>   all the appenders in that logger as well as the appenders higher in
>   the hierarchy**.  For example, if a console appender is added to the
>   root logger, then all enabled logging requests will at least print on
>   the console.
>
> If in addition a file appender is added to a logger, say C, then
>   enabled logging requests for C and C's children will print on a file
>   and on the console. It is possible to override this default behavior
>   so that appender accumulation is no longer additive by setting the
>   additivity flag to false.

Comment: May I know how could I set the additivity flag to false for the particular appender? For example, I have a appender for ERROR, and another appender for WARN. I don't want to see the WARN content included in ERROR log file. I want the WARN log solely appear in WARN log file but not in ERROR log file. May I know can this be done?